# How to print values of function pointer in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I have a pointer to a function returning a const char pointer. My question is how to print the pointer and then also the object (the string itself) referenced by the pointer(s).

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char const *func(void)
{
    printf("Printed func string.\n");
    return "Pointed func string.\n";
}

int main(void) {
    char const *(*fp)(void) = func;

    /*print statements here*/

    return 0;
}
```

I get either a `ISO C forbids conversion of function pointer to object pointer type` or some undefined behavior.

EDIT:

```
int main(void) {
    char const *(*fp)(void) = func;

    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&fp;
    /*print statements here*/
    printf("The: %p\n",(char *) p);


    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT: `0x7fff36753500`

Is not correct.

Comment: converting the function pointer to a char pointer, dereferencing it, using unsigned char *.

Comment: On Linux you might consider `dladdr` to get the name, given the address of a *global* function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char const *(*fp)(void) = func;
```

Here, you are only assigning `func` to the function pointer. You need to call it to get the string returned by the function.

```
   char const *(*fp)(void) = func;

   const char *p = fp();
   printf("In main: %s", p);
```

That's how you print the string. There's no standard format specifier to print a function pointer. `%p` is only for data pointer, not for a function pointer. So to print a function pointer using `%p` is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you really need to print the function pointer, then convert it to a character pointer and print them:

```
   unsigned char *cp = (unsigned char*)&fp;

   for(i=0;i<sizeof fp; i++) {
      printf("[%08x]", cp[i]);
   }
```

This works because converting any object to a character pointer is allowed (`char*`, `unsigned char*` or `signed char*`). What it prints is in a implementation-defined format (just like `%p`).

Comment: This "*then convert it to a character pointer*" is misleading. As your code does something different.